# How do I give spacing between Expansionpanels in ExpansionPanellist in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

My app contains multiple cards with check box which makes wheather a work is done or not.

I want to create expansion panel list which contains multiple expansion panel. But when i want to give 16px spacing between each ExpansionPanels when it's not expanded but there is no option to do that. Can you please help.

If there is any other alternative to design this layout please help.

```
ExpansionPanelList(
      // animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 10),
      expandedHeaderPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 08),
      elevation: 0,
      children: [
        ExpansionPanel(
            isExpanded: _isOpen[0],
            headerBuilder: (context, isOpen) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: 12, horizontal: 15),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "0 Month",
                      style: ThemeText.s18w500Black,
                    ),
                    Visibility(
                      visible: toggele0[0] && toggele0[1] && toggele0[2],
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          SvgPicture.asset(
                              "assets/icons/icon-vaccination-check.svg"),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 6.5,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "Done",
                            style: ThemeText.s12w400Green2,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
            body: Column(
              children: [
                CheckboxListTile(
                    controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                    activeColor: HexColor(HexColors.textColorGreen2),
                    title: Text(
                      "Oral Polio Vaccine (2nd dose)",
                      style: ThemeText.s16w400Black.copyWith(
                          decoration: toggele0[0]
                              ? TextDecoration.lineThrough
                              : TextDecoration.none),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text("Protects against Poliomyelitis"),
                    value: toggele0[0],
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        toggele0[0] = !toggele0[0];
                      });
                    }),
                CheckboxListTile(
                    controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                    activeColor: HexColor(HexColors.textColorGreen2),
                    title: Text(
                      "Oral Polio Vaccine (2nd dose)",
                      style: ThemeText.s16w400Black.copyWith(
                          decoration: toggele0[1]
                              ? TextDecoration.lineThrough
                              : TextDecoration.none),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text("Protects against Poliomyelitis"),
                    value: toggele0[1],
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        toggele0[1] = !toggele0[1];
                      });
                    }),
                CheckboxListTile(
                    controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                    activeColor: HexColor(HexColors.textColorGreen2),
                    title: Text(
                      "Oral Polio Vaccine (2nd dose)",
                      style: ThemeText.s16w400Black.copyWith(
                          decoration: toggele0[2]
                              ? TextDecoration.lineThrough
                              : TextDecoration.none),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text("Protects against Poliomyelitis"),
                    value: toggele0[2],
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        toggele0[2] = !toggele0[2];
                      });
                    })
              ],
            )),
        ExpansionPanel(
            isExpanded: _isOpen[1],
            headerBuilder: (context, isOpen) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: 12, horizontal: 15),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "1 Month",
                      style: ThemeText.s18w500Black,
                    ),
                    Visibility(
                      visible: toggele1[0] && toggele1[1] && toggele1[2],
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          SvgPicture.asset(
                              "assets/icons/icon-vaccination-check.svg"),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 6.5,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "Done",
                            style: ThemeText.s12w400Green2,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
            body: Column(
              children: [
                CheckboxListTile(
                    controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                    activeColor: HexColor(HexColors.textColorGreen2),
                    title: Text(
                      "Oral Polio Vaccine (2nd dose)",
                      style: ThemeText.s16w400Black.copyWith(
                          decoration: toggele1[0]
                              ? TextDecoration.lineThrough
                              : TextDecoration.none),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text("Protects against Poliomyelitis"),
                    value: toggele1[0],
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        toggele1[0] = !toggele1[0];
                      });
                    }),
                CheckboxListTile(
                    controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                    activeColor: HexColor(HexColors.textColorGreen2),
                    title: Text(
                      "Oral Polio Vaccine (2nd dose)",
                      style: ThemeText.s16w400Black.copyWith(
                          decoration: toggele1[1]
                              ? TextDecoration.lineThrough
                              : TextDecoration.none),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text("Protects against Poliomyelitis"),
                    value: toggele1[1],
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        toggele1[1] = !toggele1[1];
                      });
                    }),
                CheckboxListTile(
                    controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                    activeColor: HexColor(HexColors.textColorGreen2),
                    title: Text(
                      "Oral Polio Vaccine (2nd dose)",
                      style: ThemeText.s16w400Black.copyWith(
                          decoration: toggele1[2]
                              ? TextDecoration.lineThrough
                              : TextDecoration.none),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text("Protects against Poliomyelitis"),
                    value: toggele1[2],
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        toggele1[2] = !toggele1[2];
                      });
                    })
              ],
            )),]),
```

Comment: if I interpreted your question correctly then this answer will work for you..... you just have to add expandedHeaderPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),

Comment: Thanks i have edited explaination. I want to add padding when expansionpanel is not expanded.